# Create a cron that runs every friday with a specific interval

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, quartz, crontrigger

I want to create a cron that runs in this interval 16/01/2023 - 15/06/2023 every friday at 12 o'clock.

The cron that i created is "0 0 12 ? 1-6 FRI 2023" but i do not know how to put the days interval for january and june.

Comment: You cannot specify a specific year AFAIK, so you need to do something like exit if != 2023 `0 0  * 1-6 Fri`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot. Probable 3 schedules:

```
0 0 12 16-31 1 FRI 2023
0 0 12 ? 2-5 FRI 2023
0 0 12 1-15 6 FRI 2023
```